New install will no longer boot "boot file not found"
I installed Ubuntu 24.04 on a 1TB hard drive I had sitting around and had no problems at first, it worked fine installed games and programs all seemed good. After about three boots with it working perfectly fine it will no longer boot, it says error file boot not found and sits at a black screen.
it detects the one hard drive I have connected albeit in a odd way. 
As you can see it says there is a 910MB and a 480MB drive in the files, in the side bar there is also a 1TB showing up, it is strange to me, I don't understand why. The USB drive I am booting from is only 200MB.
I also took a screenshot of gparted

I ran boot repair and it said:
"The boot files of [sda2 (end>100GB)] are far from the start of the disk.
Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partiton via the [separate/boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair}. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)The boot of your PC is in UEFI mode. You may want to retry after changing it to BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode"
I partitioned the drive a

You seem to have a newer (after 2012) UEFI system, but have installed Ubuntu in old BIOS boot mode to gpt partitioned drive. Microsoft required Windows 8s to be installed in UEFI/gpt mode since 2012, so systems are UEFI.  How you boot install/repair media is how it installs or repairs. But how system boots is a setting in UEFI for UEFI or BIOS/CSM/Legacy mode. If new install probably better to reinstall in UEFI mode. You then use gpt partitioning, must have an ESP - efi system partition (FAT32) and / (root). Many prefer a smaller / if using a larger drive and separate /home or data partition.
